# How to prevent multiple click on a like button with likes counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, redux, material-ui

I created a Like button component, it contains a button and a likes counter text field.
Each button click changes the state from like to dislike state, or from dislike to like state.
When I quickly press on a button several times its changes the counter value more than once.
How to prevent this behavior?

```
const LikeButton = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

    const likePostHandler = () =>{
        dispatch(likePost(props.post_ID, token))
    }
    
    const unlikePostHandler = () =>{
        dispatch(unlikePost(props.post_ID, token))
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={classes.button}>
            {props.isLiked && (
                <Tooltip 
                    onClick={unlikePostHandler} 
                    title="Undo like" 
                    placement="top"
                >
                    <FavoriteIcon color="primary"/>
                </Tooltip>
            )}
            {!props.isLiked && (
                <Tooltip 
                    onClick={likePostHandler} 
                    title="Like" 
                    placement="top"
                >
                    <FavoriteBorderIcon color="primary"/>
                </Tooltip>
            )}
            <span className={classes.span}>{props.likesCounter} Likes</span>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default LikeButton
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debounce` for prevent on click

```
import {debounce} from 'lodash'

const handleClickButton = debounce(() => {
    console.log('click')
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do things like this by saving a boolean, so if you click the button the boolean turns true and if it is true you can't click the button anymore.

Ex.

```
pressed = false;
if(!pressed){
    // Do things
    pressed = true;
}
```

Comment: This is approach works. I'd simply add that if Thanh is using Redux, a state check (preferably), or setTimeout will be necessary for setting `pressed` back to false